# SQLAlchemy unstable behaviour with Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to resolve an SQLAlchemy issue that I'm having and narrowed it down to this simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "oracle+cx_oracle://<user>:<password>@<sid>"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Instance(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

with app.app_context():
    instance = db.session.query(Instance).filter(Instance.id == 105250).first()
    print(instance)
```

The instance with id 105250 does indeed exists in the database, but the results I'm getting are quite surprising:

```
% x.py
<__main__.Instance object at 0x7f65461cdef0>
% x.py
<__main__.Instance object at 0x7f0c09aa2ef0>
% x.py
None
% x.py
<__main__.Instance object at 0x7fd1c7a9eef0>
% x.py
None
```

Can anyone explain how to prevent and fix this unstable behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. Posting it here, in case someone runs into the same issue.

The problem was caused by unstable cx_Oracle 5.2.0 driver. Downgrading it to 5.1.3 fixed the issue.